# SyndicationFeed & SyndicationItem LastUpdatedTime

Tags: c#, .net, rss

I'm trying to use the SyndicationFeed class to get content from a feed, but for some feeds it works ok but for others it doesn't.

For example, when I want to get feeds from http://www.alistapart.com/site/rss , the LastUpdatedTime has a value of 01-01-0001 for all feed items and the feed itself.
Is there something that i need to do? or is it maybe that SyndicationFeed doesn't support all websites to read from them all the information?

some sample code that i'm using :

```
var feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(XmlReader.Create("http://www.alistapart.com/site/rss"));
var feedPosts = feed.Items; // here all feedPosts have the invalid LastUpdatedTime, but if i go to the website i can see that there is actually one
```

Comment: Are you pulling from RSS feed or Atom? Are the fields the same name? try manually parsing the date/time from the feed and see what you get.

Comment: I shouldn't parse anything, the idea of the class is that it does that job for you... of course i can parse it, but i don't want to create a custom parser for every type of feed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the `LastUpdatedTime` while the date in the RSS you mentioned is not `LastUpdatedTime` nor the more common date `pubDate`. Note the namespace which is `"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"`.

Most of these elements are optional and you must be able to live without them or use alternative ones.

I have create a Podcast software and I have found the `SyndicationFeed` implementation very poor and brittle to deal with various dates which are there in the real world.

### UPDATE

> is there a way to use the framework's
>   classes to parse this non standard
>   attributes?

Yes, have a look at [Element Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.elementextensions.aspx).

Comment: is there a way to use the framework's classes to parse this non standard attributes? i would just need the published date and a couple of other things (in general the content of the feed and the title is always there). if not, what do you suggest?